# Dereference twice in gdb

Tags: c, gdb

I find myself doing the following to find the location of a pointer and then the string that it points to:

```
// char* strings[2] = {"Hello", "Brando"};

>>> x/g $rbp-32               
0x7fffffffe0d0: 0x0000555555554a3e
>>> x/s 0x0000555555554a3e <-- manually typed in now
0x555555554a3e: "Hello"
```

Is there a better way to do a double dereference? Ultimately I would like to do something like?

```
>>> xx $rbp-32
0x7fffffffe0d0: 0x0000555555554a3e: "Hello"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(gdb) p *(char**)($rbp-0x20)
$1 = 0x555555556004 "Hello"

(gdb) p *(char**)($rbp-0x20)@2
$2 = {0x555555556004 "Hello", 0x55555555600a "Brando"}

# This could easily be transformed into a user-defined command so as to avoid repetition.
(gdb) printf "0x%x: 0x%x: %s\n", ($rbp-0x20), *(char**)($rbp-0x20), *(char**)($rbp-0x20)
0xffffdb00: 0x55556004: Hello
```

> could you please explain what the @2 does?

From the [documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Arrays.html#Arrays):

```
you can print the contents of array with

p *array@len
The left operand of ‘@’ must reside in memory. Array values made with ‘@’ in this way behave just like other arrays in terms of subscripting, and are coerced to pointers when used in expressions.
```

Comment: thanks, could you please explain what the `@2` does? `p *(char**) ($rbp-32)` works for me!

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 I've updated the answer.